# MS Web Deploy error registry editing has been disabled by your administrator

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application which I have compiled into a deployment package using web deploy. This works on ALL of the machines I have installed it to, except for 1.

I get this error when I try to deploy my website

[image: error]

1) It is a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine (I have gotten it to work with other machines on a similar set up)
2) I'm logged in with an administrator account
3) Latest MS Web Deploy is installed

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that it's a company policy that registry editing is disallowed in my case (desktop), but I overcame this by manually setting MSDeployPath in the batch script we use to call X.deploy.cmd, e.g.

set MSDeployPath=C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\

before calling

call %system.build.project.package%\X.deploy.cmd

I found this by looking at the contents of %system.build.project.package%\X.deploy.cmd to see where it needed registry access.

Answer (score 0):

In my case [UnHookExec.inf](http://securityresponse.symantec.com/avcenter/UnHookExec.inf) by symantec helped.

Save [UnHookExec.inf](http://securityresponse.symantec.com/avcenter/UnHookExec.inf) and install it by right clicking and selecting install. (It won't show any popup or notice box.)

[Here](http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2011/04/enable-regedit-registry-editor.html) are some other method described, how to get rid of this error.